# Clicking on a WPF datagrid item is not being reflected in the observable collection in view model

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a WPF MVVM application which has an WPF Toolkit datagrid that is bound to an observable collection. One of the columns is a DataGridTemplateColumn which  implements a column of toggle buttons:

```
<dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LlistatDocuments}"                
             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
             CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
             SelectionMode="Single"                 
             ColumnWidth="*"
             AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="Bisque" 
             Focusable="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
             CellStyle="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering}"
             GridLinesVisibility="All">

   <dg:DataGrid.Resources>
         <proxy:BindingProxy x:Key="myProxy" Data="{Binding}" />
   </dg:DataGrid.Resources>

   <dg:DataGrid.Columns>

         <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selection" 
                                    MinWidth="65" Width="Auto" 
                                    CanUserResize="False">

            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton Background="Transparent" Content="" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Data.IsSelected, Source={StaticResource myProxy}, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                                    <Image MaxWidth="32" MaxHeight="32">
                                        <Image.Style>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="/My.App.Graphics;component/Images/Unchecked.png" />
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, 
                                                                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                                                           AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="/DiR.Utilitats.RecursosGrafics;component/PNG/Checked.png" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Image.Style>
                                    </Image>
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

         </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid
```

**Model**:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**:

```
private ObservableCollection<MyModel> _myDataGridItems;
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyDataGridItems
{
    get
    {
        return this._myDataGridItems;
    }

    set
    {
        this._myDataGridItems = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyDataGridItems");
    }
}

private bool _isSelected;
public bool IsSelected
{
    get
    {
        return this._isSelected;
    }

    set
    {
        this._isSelected = value;

        // Do other stuff. 
        // Here MyDataGridItems collection has not changed to selected yet for the selected item.

        OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }
}
```

**Proxy**:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

When I click on a datagrid item (DataGridTemplateColumn column), IsSelected property is correctly reached but at this point the corresponding item within the MyDataGridItems collection has not changed to IsSelected=true or IsSelected=false yet. Why? This change is not reflected in MyDataGridItems collection yet.

Comment: What's the purpose of BindingProxy? It looks odd to me. MyModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and you should bind to it directly in the CellTemplate. And what is `LlistatDocuments`?

Comment: The proxy makes possible to see IsSelected property on view model.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your sample code is too complicated: you could have spared us image changing triggers :P

As for your problem, I have no idea why you need binding proxy.

Secondly, ObservableCollection will not do what you think. ObservableCollection only notifies about changes of the collection: adding new items or deleting existing, moving them inside collection etc.

If you want to bind to properties of objects inside ObservableCollection and have UI react to them changing, your objects have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Your BindingProxy tries to emulate that - DependencyProperties also notify about changes.

So, I would suggest to rename MyModel to MyModetlDTO (or something like that) and then make another MyModel, whoose properties notify about changes. You can easily convert between them using tool like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/).

Then, in your datagrid that has ItemsSource bound to your ObservableCollection (which implements INotifyPropertyChanged) you just do:

```
<dg:DataGrid.Columns>

         <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selection" 
                                    MinWidth="65" Width="Auto" 
                                    CanUserResize="False">

            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton Background="Transparent" Content="" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
```

and automagically it works.